# Crystal Report redistributable for Windows Server 2008? - An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, windows-server-2008

First at all, thanks everyone.

What do I need to get work crystal report on windows server 2008?

Or how can I get work rpt files (loaded by code and flush it to browser) on a website (framework 3.5/4.0) running on a windows server 2008 ?

I mean, I load some rpt files (built them on crystal report 2008) and then using crystal object to export the file to xls/pdf, change the headers, make a flush to the browser and it works, this on windows server 2003/Seven/XP but the site doesn't work on Windows server 2008, I guess that I need a redistributable, but, which one ?

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

This was the error I got:

> An error has occurred while attemting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient, or the Crystal Rerports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedis*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports Runtime (x86,x64x,Itanium) required. Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve or kind of, this issue (if you have it) try setting the "Enable 32-bit Applications" to **TRUE** after just installed the CRRedistributable name it as "CRRuntime_12_0_mlb.exe" (I'm not pretty sure, but this one comes in a compressed file).

Right now I don't have the file in some server, but as soon as I can, I will leave a link here.

While you're installing the Redistributable, you will be warned about a dll (something about "print"), just ignore it, I suppose it's because the server doesn't have the spoolsv service running, but thats just my guess.

[image]

And this is the error I just got before:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the 
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required. Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What type of Windows Server edition is it: 32-bit or 64-bit? I guess, Windows Server 2008 is available in 64-bit only. This [link](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#08) contains a [32-bit installer](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communityCS/FilesAndUpdates/CRRedist2008_x86.zip) and a [64-bit installer](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communityCS/FilesAndUpdates/CRRedist2008_x64.zip). You can scroll down the page to see more.

Comment: It is Windows S. 2008 64-bit. Thanks I'm gonna check them.

Comment: It says, that the software (both) are already installed, but I just post a solution (kind of).